# Unexpected view error after migrating to new api

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

If I use this instruction:

```python
residue = fields.Float('Residue', store=False)
```

I get this error:

```
Field(s) 'arch' failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition
```

But if I use this one:

```python
_columns = {        
    'residue': fields.float('Residue', store=False),
}
```

I don't get any error. Why is this happening?

The first one uses the new API and the last one uses the old API.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you remove the `store=False`? There is another guy with the same error [here](https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/help-1/question/store-false-brings-error-89131). How are you using the field? Should it be a related field or a computed field? I think the attribute `store=False` makes sense only in those cases

Comment: @ChesuCR Removing the store=False will fix the problem, but why does it work with the old api?